# Do I need to dicretely install fs module in node

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to use `readFile` from `fs` module(node version 5.3.0). But I get an error saying module not found. Do i need to install `fs` module separately? If so exactly what package to install? It is not available by default?

Tried using fs as:

```
var freader = require('fs');
freader.readFile(...
```

Comment: `fs` it's a native node.js module, you don't need _install_ it.

Comment: Yes. @alexmac that is what I understood too. This is why I am irked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system) is the documentation about `fs`.

> File I/O is provided by simple wrappers around standard POSIX
>   functions. To use this module do require('fs'). All the methods have
>   asynchronous and synchronous forms.

---

You have no `npm` package to install, it's included in `node.js`.

---

**EDIT**: [here is the documentation of fs for node v5.3](https://nodejs.org/dist/v5.3.0/docs/api/fs.html#fs_file_system) and it's the same

Comment: Yes, @Gregory. I know it should be there by default. But still the issue. Let me try a reinstall.

Comment: What is the exact stack trace you have?

Comment: Thanks!!.Accepting as this is correct as I tried using it with a simple js file which is working fine without any extra installation. So the issue is around using it with angular which I am trying to.